# How to parse a list and a dictionary (openAPI and Swagger) in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, openapi-generator

I request a list of stock:

```
stocks = client.market.market_stocks_get() 
tickers_list = stocks.payload.instruments
```

I have an HTTP API response like this:

```
[
{'currency': 'USD',
 'figi': 'BBG000HLJ7M4',
 'isin': 'US45867G1013',
 'lot': 1,
 'min_price_increment': 0.01,
 'name': 'InterDigItal Inc',
 'ticker': 'IDCC',
 'type': 'Stock'}, 
 {'currency': 'USD',
 'figi': 'BBG000PSXT64',
 'isin': 'US21676P1030',
 'lot': 1,
 'min_price_increment': 0.01,
 'name': 'Cooper-Standard Holdings Inc',
 'ticker': 'CPS',
 'type': 'Stock'},
 {'currency': 'USD',
 'figi': 'BBG005BT60Y8',
 'isin': 'US62945V1098',
 'lot': 1,
 'min_price_increment': 0.01,
 'name': 'NV5 Global Inc',
 'ticker': 'NVEE',
 'type': 'Stock'}
 ]
```

I need to get all values of the keys "ticker".

Before to do that, for test, I just try to read first value directly.

```
print(tickers_list[0]["ticker"])
```

After that, I got the error:

```
<class 'openapi_genclient.models.market_instrument.MarketInstrument'>
    print(tickers_list[0]["ticker"])
TypeError: 'MarketInstrument' object is not subscriptable
```

I wanted to check the type of this key:

```
print(type(tickers_list[0]))
```

And I see it is not a dictionary, but

```
<class 'openapi_genclient.models.market_instrument.MarketInstrument'>
```

I confused .The question is: How to get the value of the key "ticker" ?

Comment: As you see its not a ``dict``, try ``dir(tickers_list[0])`` to check what are the supported methods & see if any method exists to convert to dict.

Comment: I got this information:
'_ticker', '_type', 'attribute_map', 'currency', 'discriminator', 'figi', 'isin', 'local_vars_configuration', 'lot', 'min_price_increment', 'name', 'openapi_types', 'ticker', 'to_dict', 'to_str', 'type'

Comment: ``tickers_list[0].to_dict()['ticker']`` ??

Answer (score 0):

Solution (thanks to Sushanth):

```
print(tickers_list[0].ticker)
```

or

```
tickers_list[0].to_dict()['ticker']
```

Checking

```
print(type(tickers_list[0].ticker))
print(type(tickers_list[0].to_dict()['ticker']))
```

Output:

```
IDCC
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```