# How to convert a list of dictionaries to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am utilizing the API here: https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/master/docs/GamesApi.md#get_games that returns a list of dictionaries and want to get the data into a format that I can manipulate or store it into a database. I have attempted to convert it to a pandas dataframe with the pd.DataFrame() method as outlined in this question: [Convert list of dictionaries to a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638006/convert-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-pandas-dataframe). I first have stored the API response as a variable `api_response = api_instance.get_games()`, then converted it to a DataFrame with `df = pd.DataFrame(api_response)`. Printing that DataFrame returns only one column containing the entire dictionary for each game instance instead of splitting out columns by key and populating with values.

And example of how the data is returned for two games from `print(api_response)` is in the following format:

```
[{'attendance': None,
 'away_conference': 'FBS Independents',
 'away_id': 87,
 'away_line_scores': [7, 10, 21, 0, 3],
 'away_points': 41,
 'away_post_win_prob': 0.44707054087049625,
 'away_team': 'Notre Dame',
 'conference_game': True,
 'excitement_index': 7.4132284343,
 'highlights': None,
 'home_conference': 'ACC',
 'home_id': 52,
 'home_line_scores': [7, 7, 6, 18, 0],
 'home_points': 38,
 'home_post_win_prob': 0.5529294591295038,
 'home_team': 'Florida State',
 'id': 401282614,
 'neutral_site': False,
 'notes': None,
 'season': 2021,
 'season_type': 'regular',
 'start_date': '2021-09-05T23:30:00.000Z',
 'start_time_tbd': False,
 'venue': 'Bobby Bowden Field at Doak Campbell Stadium',
 'venue_id': 3697,
 'week': 1}, {'attendance': None,
 'away_conference': 'ACC',
 'away_id': 97,
 'away_line_scores': [0, 0, 10, 14],
 'away_points': 24,
 'away_post_win_prob': 0.04096564974450303,
 'away_team': 'Louisville',
 'conference_game': False,
 'excitement_index': 4.6236823229,
 'highlights': None,
 'home_conference': 'SEC',
 'home_id': 145,
 'home_line_scores': [9, 17, 3, 14],
 'home_points': 43,
 'home_post_win_prob': 0.959034350255497,
 'home_team': 'Ole Miss',
 'id': 401282055,
 'neutral_site': True,
 'notes': None,
 'season': 2021,
 'season_type': 'regular',
 'start_date': '2021-09-07T00:00:00.000Z',
 'start_time_tbd': False,
 'venue': 'Mercedes-Benz Stadium',
 'venue_id': 5348,
 'week': 1}]
```

Is there a better way to store this that I am overlooking?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(your_data)` returns a dataframe with 2 rows and 26 columns.

Comment: I am storing the API response as a variable ```api_response = api_instance.get_games(year=year, week=week, id=id)``` where I specify year, week, and game id parameters. Whenever I try to convert it to a DataFrame ```df = pd.DataFrame(api_response)``` and print the result, it returns a DataFrame with one row and one column containing the entire contents of a dictionary. I used two games as the example in my original question, just to note.

Comment: Updated my original question to explain this a bit better.

Comment: Did you try `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(your_data, orient='index')`?

Comment: Does `api_response` actually contain the parsed, nested data structure? Or does it contain a *single string* with JSON data?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel. From [the documentation](https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/master/docs/GamesApi.md#get_games), the API call return a list of `Game`.

Comment: I did try the ```from_dict``` function but it returns "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'" @Corralien

Comment: Can you try: `type(my_list[0])`

Comment: Printing that returns ```<class 'cfbd.models.game.Game'>``` Printing just the type of the variable ```api_response``` returns ```<class 'list'>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code, `Game` object have a method [`to_dict`](https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/f1c210701bda0f279edf52fb38b4620678a8f132/cfbd/models/game.py#L726):

Try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([game.to_dict() for game in api_response])
```

**Note**:

This problem has been discussed previously, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997174/how-to-convert-list-of-model-objects-to-pandas-dataframe/41762270). In order for pandas to convert this to a `DataFrame` we need to make sure that we're actually dealing with a list of dictionaries.

Usually we might `print` our `api_response` and look at the data. In this case, this is not enough. Because even though `api_response` looks (read more about `__repr__` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)) like a list of dictionaries, it's actually a list of `Game` objects.

We can learn this by printing the type of the first element in our list:

```
>>> print(type(api_response[0]))
<class 'cfbd.models.game.Game'>
```

Some classes will have a `to_dict` method attached to them. If they don't, you can use `vars` instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([vars(game) for game in api_response])
```

Comment: Maybe explain why Game might look like a dict when printing but really isn't.

Comment: @user3471881. This is the representation `__repr__` of the object. Check [this code](https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/f1c210701bda0f279edf52fb38b4620678a8f132/cfbd/models/game.py#L753-L759) and you will understand. `__repr__` calls `to_str` which call `to_dict`.

Comment: @user3471881 You can see it here: https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/f1c210701bda0f279edf52fb38b4620678a8f132/cfbd/models/game.py#L757

Comment: @Corralien you're always a step ahead :)

Comment: My point was that you can add this to the answer so that it might help someone who has a similar problem with lists of objects that look like dictionaries but are in fact...not :)

Comment: @user3471881. try: `repr([{'a': 0}, {'b': 1}])`. It looks like a list of dicts? but it's a string. This is the same case with Python base types.

Comment: I know. And a lot of pandas users on this forum are *not* familiar with Python basics.

Comment: If we don't expand in the answer to give other users (that don't use this specific API) some guidance - I think this answer belongs in a comment and the question should probably be deleted. (imo)

Comment: @user3471881. I updated my answer. Feel free to amend it.

Comment: Very strange design choice IMO to have a class that doesn't subclass `dict`, but looks exactly like one in its `__repr__`. I *guess* the intent is to make it easier to serialize back to JSON, but I don't think that actually works. I would file an issue about it, honestly.

Comment: "This class is auto generated by the swagger code generator program." Found this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63100487/how-to-parse-a-list-and-a-dictionary-openapi-and-swagger-in-python.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this

```
df = DataFrame.from_dict('col_1'=api_response.keys(), 'col_2'=api_response.values())
```

Comment: Because it is returned as a list object, it does not have a 'keys' attribute.

Comment: Change the type of the list to dict

Answer (score 0):

[image]May be you could try checking type of the data received from API,

```
type(api_response)
```

Below code gives exact output that you're looking for which returns a dataframe with 2 rows and 26 columns

```
import pandas as pd
d1=[{'attendance': None,'away_conference': 'FBS Independents','away_id': 87,'away_line_scores': [7, 10, 21, 0, 3],'away_points': 41,'away_post_win_prob': 0.44707054087049625,'away_team': 'Notre Dame','conference_game': True,'excitement_index': 7.4132284343,'highlights': None,'home_conference': 'ACC','home_id': 52,'home_line_scores': [7, 7, 6, 18, 0],'home_points': 38,'home_post_win_prob': 0.5529294591295038,'home_team': 'Florida State','id': 401282614,'neutral_site': False,'notes': None,'season': 2021,'season_type': 'regular','start_date': '2021-09-05T23:30:00.000Z','start_time_tbd': False,'venue': 'Bobby Bowden Field at Doak Campbell Stadium','venue_id': 3697,'week': 1}, {'attendance': None,'away_conference': 'ACC','away_id': 97,'away_line_scores': [0, 0, 10, 14],'away_points': 24,'away_post_win_prob': 0.04096564974450303,'away_team': 'Louisville','conference_game': False,'excitement_index': 4.6236823229,'highlights': None,'home_conference': 'SEC','home_id': 145,'home_line_scores': [9, 17, 3, 14],'home_points': 43,'home_post_win_prob': 0.959034350255497,'home_team': 'Ole Miss','id': 401282055,'neutral_site': True,'notes': None,'season': 2021,'season_type': 'regular','start_date': '2021-09-07T00:00:00.000Z','start_time_tbd': False,'venue': 'Mercedes-Benz Stadium','venue_id': 5348,'week': 1}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
display(df)
```

Comment: ```print(type(api_response))
``` returns ```<class 'list'>```

Answer (score 0):

From the source codes, [GamesApi.get_games](https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/f1c210701bda0f279edf52fb38b4620678a8f132/cfbd/api/games_api.py#L460) returns a list of [Games](https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/f1c210701bda0f279edf52fb38b4620678a8f132/cfbd/models/game.py#L22). And from there you can see that it has a [to_dict](https://github.com/CFBD/cfbd-python/blob/f1c210701bda0f279edf52fb38b4620678a8f132/cfbd/models/game.py#L726) method, which allows you create a dataframe from list of dictionaries.